# Restrict the user from typing more than three characters in a TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i want to restrict the user from typing more than three characters in a textfield, i tried the "restrict" propriety of the TextField but i didn't find anything about the number of characters that you can allow the user to type, but rather i found restrictions regarding the type of characters allowed. so how can i achieve what i want? this is what i've tried:

```
var theTextField:TextField = new TextField();
theTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
theTextField.border = true;
theTextField.x = 10;
theTextField.y = 10;
theTextField.multiline = true;
theTextField.wordWrap = true;
addChild(theTextField);

theTextField.restrict="0-9"
```

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#maxChars

Comment: Thank you a tonne, i really don't know how i missed it.